# AndroidAsyncHttp onFailure error messages

Tags: java, android, http, android-async-http

I'm trying out the AndroidAsyncHttp library for Android downloaded from http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ and am trying to find the best way to evaluate any connection errors within the onFailure(Throwable error, String response) callback.  Ideally I'd like to see the HTTP status code returned e.g. 401,403,500 etc.  Is there any way of doing this?  So far I've only been able to get a string from error.getMessage() or error.toString().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, managed to figure out all the different error scenarios just combinations of error.getMessage(), error.toString() and error.getCause()

Comment: Turns out trial and error is the only way. It would have been nice to access http status code to understand the problem from developer's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException;

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
    if (e instanceof HttpResponseException) {
        HttpResponseException ex = (HttpResponseException) e;
        int statusCode = ex.getStatusCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: e is not an instance HttpResponseException class. It seems to be an instance of ConnectionException class. Perhaps some class the library guy created. Turns out trial and error is the only way. It would have been nice to access http status code to understand the problem from developer's perspective.

Comment: The one the poster is using is from http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ which is that guy's custom class. So you are correct. I think you are using the base version from github.